# past or passed?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, time

Please help choose: past or passed.
The newly-crowned first king of Italy announced, "The time of the Roman Empire is _____."

(Please pretend the king spoke English.) I'm writing a transcript of a spoken recording (not about Rome), and I don't know which word was said, but I must use one of the two. The speaker definitely said is, not has. Other questions I've found here about past and passed don't quite have this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose 'past'. 'Passed' is the past participle of the verb 'pass' and would have been preceded by 'has'; 'past' can be an adjective meaning 'gone by in time and no longer existing', or 'finished', e.g. the danger is now past.

[Past (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/past)